# tx_news and roq_newsevent: integrate plugin via TypoScript

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

I am upgrading tt_news + mbl_newsevent to their successors tx_news + (probably) roq_newsevent.

I am still missing out on how to access roq_newsevent data in a template when integrating (trying to) it via TypoScript.

Another community member has asked the same question on TYPO3 forge https://forge.typo3.org/issues/61060 before, but no answer.

I would expect it's just extbase basics, I haven't seen a plugin that can only be used via flexform, is it?

EDIT (returns no news):

```
temp.newslist = USER
temp.newslist {
   userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
   extensionName = News
   pluginName = Pi1
   switchableControllerActions {
         News {
           1 = eventList
         }
   }
   settings < plugin.tx_news.settings
   settings.startingpoint = {$pidRecords}
   settings.recursive = 1
   settings.detailPid = {$pidDetail}
   view =< plugin.tx_news.view
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using "eventList" als switchableControllerAction?

Comment: That would be `switchableControllerActions.News.1 = eventList`, right? It does something, but returns "No News available". I'll post the snippet I've been using above (but have already given up on roq_newsevent to say the truth - see my clone of your importer script https://github.com/fsaris/news_ttnewsimport/pull/15)

Comment: Probably the easiest way would have been to add and configure the News plugin using Event list on a folder page and then just use the RECORDS TypoScript object to use this plugin somewhere in the page. If you want information about this approach, let me know.

Comment: Yes I did that using CONTENT. But I like to have TypoScript control :-)